# Spark dataframe. Add columns from a existing json column

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a `Dataset[(Long, String)]` that contains an id and a json String
It's built more or less like this:

```
val ids: Dataset[Long] = ...
val results = ids.mapPartitions( ids => {
   // Create http client
   .
   .
   ids.map( id => (id, getJsonById(id))
   }
```

If I run `results.toDF` it will create a dataframe with the id and a string with the json, but what I want to have is a Dataframe with the id and all columns that are in the json.

How can I achieve that?

Edit: I want to load the whole json as dataframe, not a particular field of it.
Something like what `sparkContext.read.json(jsonRDD: RDD[String])` would do.

Thanks

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238367/how-to-extract-values-from-json-string-in-spark?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, with that I can create a new column with a value inside the json, but in my case I want to have the whole json structure in the dataframe